# How to insert table values from one MySQL database to another MySQL database when they are on 2 different servers with different ports?

Tags: mysql, sql, perl

I have one MySQL db on server A and another MySQL instance on a server B. There is a need to copy records (fastest possible) from one table to another (based on user providing ID for records that match) from server A -> B many times during the day. 
Is there a way to create an SQL statement to do this or data need to be extracted by some programming language (e.g. Perl, Python etc.), then store result in variables and then prepare Insert statement in order to to insert data to server B?
Servers have 2 different IPs and DBs are on 2 different ports but they are the same version of MySQL (5.6.29).

Comment: Are you trying to mirror the entire database, copy an entire table, copy a subset of records into a table with the same structure, copy a subset of records into a table with a different structure, or something else entirely?

Comment: Copy subset of records (also selected columns) from one table to another - edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the [replication facilities](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-table) of MySQL

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to just comment, but I think the easiest approach would be to create a view on server A with just that data that server B needs, then create a cron job on server B to periodically query the view & import the data during the day. For the job on B I would suggest you script it and create logfiles for debugging, but you could just put a mysql command in your crontab if you want it quick and dirty.